# can not build react project due to webpack

Tags: javascript

I am bumping in a annoying issue. I am trying to buişd a project using web3 upon other things and I get some compilation error I can not sort out :

```
Compiled with problems: X

ERROR in ../node_modules/cipher-base/index.js 3:16-43

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\CAS\node_modules\cipher-base'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
    - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
```

I tried lots of things but can not manage to get it work out.
Can someone help?

Comment: just to be precise, I tested all that is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70557596/couldnt-import-web3-library-in-react-application but could not get it to work

Comment: The error seems pretty clear on how to resolve it.

Comment: This question lacks a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it o work

adding at the root of the website : webpack.config

containing :

```
    module.exports = {
resolve: {
    fallback: {
        assert: require.resolve('assert'),
        crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
        http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
        https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
        os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
        stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
    },
},
// Webpack 5 is enabled by default
// You can still use webpack 4 while upgrading to the latest version of Next.js by adding the "webpack5: false" flag
webpack5: false,
```

};